# How to fill Pyplot Polygons with a hatch pattern

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is probably ridiculously simple. All I want is to fill a set of Polygons with a hatch pattern, but the pattern never ever appears; I've played with parameters like `fill` and `facecolor` without success. The following is a minimal working example

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection, LineCollection
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc


region1 = [(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)]
region2 = [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2)]
polygon1=plt.Polygon(region1,closed=True,fill=False,hatch='/')
polygon2=plt.Polygon(region2,closed=True,fill=False,hatch='\\')
patches = PatchCollection([polygon1,polygon2],match_original=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_collection(patches)

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: See docs of the [collections api](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.AsteriskPolygonCollection.set_hatch): *Unlike other properties such as linewidth and colors, hatching can only be specified for the collection as a whole, not separately for each member.* So, you'll need a solution without the PatchCollection

Comment: As you can't use a PatchCollection, an option is to add the polygons individually: `ax.add_patch(polygon1); ax.add_patch(polygon2)`

Comment: That worked indeed, thanks.